# C# Httpwebrequest detection

Tags: javascript, c#, php, ssl, https

What ways are there for a website to detect automated connections made through C# Httpwebrequest?

Such as c#'s default user-agent? Operating System? or what..
have this problem with any other language, just C#?
I'm being blocked from accessing a certain website using Httpwebrequest, I don't

Also it's definitely not my IP address & nor are there any faults in my code as I've tested connections to other websites which work just fine.. Also I stated above I can make connections to the website using C++, C, Vb.net, Java, Python & so on, there is also no difference in header information either.

EDIT:

```
    // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/overall.ws");
// Set the Method property of the request to POST.
request.Method = "POST";
// Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
string postData = "user1=Zezima&submit=Search";
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);
// Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
// Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
// Get the request stream.
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
// Write the data to the request stream.
dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
// Close the Stream object.
dataStream.Close ();
// Get the response.
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
// Display the status.
Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
// Read the content.
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
// Display the content.
Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
// Clean up the streams.
reader.Close ();
dataStream.Close ();
response.Close ();
```

Comment: What do you mean by blocked, you receive an exception when you try to take the response or what ?

Comment: Well the connection is made but I get no html/php response, no data just a blank page.

Comment: Without any details we can't help you, if the webservice is public you can post some code and try something. Also check the content type, if the webservice is private and open only for you/your company contact them and ask them why they don't return any response.

Comment: @mybirthname Added the script & url/post data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private const string Url = "http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/overall.ws";


    private static HttpWebRequest BuildWebRequest()
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(Url) as HttpWebRequest;

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Timeout = 40000;
        request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = true;

        string body = "user1=Zezima&submit=Search";

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(body);

        using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

        return request;


    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = BuildWebRequest();

                var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                var responseContent = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                Console.Write("Success - " + response.StatusCode);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                 Console.Write(e);
            }
    }
```

I can take the response from the website. It is not empty.